# Python: Does 'unittest' have something that 'doctest' hasn't?

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

The question is quite clear, ... note however that I am NOT asking about a feature comparison (there are a lot of them already), nor am I asking about which one you prefer !

I have myself a clear preference for doctests, I use them for everything, even if those are not to be used for documentation. But what I am wondering is : is there anything you can do with unitests that you cannot do with doctests ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some test scenarios doctests simply don't cover very well. That's OK since, as Lie pointed out, doctests aren't meant to be a comprehensive testing solution - they're meant to ensure that simple interactive-prompt style examples in your documentation (including docstrings) don't get out of date.

Writing actual unit tests, on the other hand, allows you to unlimber the full power of Python in deciding how to compose your test suite (e.g. using inheritance to share not only test set up and tear down operations, but also actual test methods).

doctests may be a part of that, but they aren't a complete testing solution (except for small, relatively self-contained operations).

It's probably worth browsing Python's own test suite (the `test` package) and taking a look at some of the tests in there. While doctests play their part, most of it is written using `unittest`.

Comment: +1 "allows you to unlimber the full power of Python in deciding how to compose your test suite". That's very true ... I had never thought about that.

Comment: Once you start doing scenario testing involving interactions between multiple modules, the benefits of the additional power provided by `unittest` certainly become much clearer. `doctest` can handle straightforward unit testing of a bottom level module without many dependencies, but it struggles with tests that need more than that (e.g. many of the networking tests in the stdlib actually start up a test server in another thread. The code to create and destroy the server can easily be shared between tests in `unittest`, but it is harder in `doctest`)

Comment: It is harder, but not SO hard... you can basically write a module testutils.py that contains shared test utility code. In a project I am doing, I actually do exactly that ("starting up a test server in another thread").
What you said is a really good point, but forgetting about all this (and honestly) don't you think that it is way cooler, nicer and more natural to write doctests ?

Comment: I think `doctest` is a cool module, and a useful part of a more comprehensive test suite, but I see it as far more feasible to use `unittest` without `doctest` for a test suite than the other way around.

Comment: Ok ... so I know what my dream test framework would be : object-like doctests. I have to say I used to use unittest, and I still do when it's not my project, but as soon as I work on my own stuff, I write only doctests, because I dislike very much this 'assertTrue(blabla)' thingy. I think it is very hard to read. Furthermore, I very often do some kind of test-driven development, I begin with writing full test suite (with doctests) in order to design a nice easy-to-use interface for the classes/functions I'll write later. That way things are much more visual ! And you actually do 3 things at th

Comment: ...e same time : designing a user-interface, writing tests, and writing doc. AND I never stumbled upon a big obstacle that I could have overcome easily with using unittest. That's actually why asked this question !

Comment: I'm wondering if our different perspectives may have something to do with the kind of testing we each typically do, rather than simply being differences in personal preference (although I'm sure the latter is also part of it). For example, I'm now actually somewhat curious as to how you might rewrite tests like `test.test_cmd_line_script` and `test.test_runpy` with `doctest` instead of `unittest`.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I could actually re-write easily those tests with doctests, but it wouldn't make that much sense. I very often do some prototyping, rather high-level, and for that reason it is very easy to get started with doctests without even having code. Most of the time also I write the documentation around those tests, like one sentence, one very readable test. It is true that in the case of test.test_cmd_line_script, which is probably not supposed to be so user-friendly, other considerations like the robustness of tests are certainly the priority.

Comment: But actually, this whole talk, made me think that sometimes I also use doctests where it doesn't make much sense ... Maybe I should start using unitests again for some cases.

Answer (score 5):

There is a widespread misconception that doctest is for testing your code. doctest is intended for *testing your documentation*. doctest is intended to test that your documentation matches what the function/class/module is actually doing, and alerts you if sample code in your documentation becomes obsolete as the module evolves.

While doctest might reveal bugs in the code, it is not its primary purpose (e.g. like a change in code might unravel bugs in a unittest's testcase code, but testing the testcase code is not unitetest's primary purpose)

> even if those are not to be used for documentation

docstring are automatically extracted out by help() function to become documentation for your 
function/class/module; you cannot make a docstring not a documentation. Users of your module/function/class (or you in a few days) might try to do help() on your function/class/module and get a surprise that the documentation is a bunch of codes.

Comment: The misconception is apparently so widespread that it extends to the official documentation, which states, "Doctest also makes an excellent tool for regression testing." https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html

Answer (score 0):

Doctests are limited to per function (or per class) tests. You cannot do things like taking the output of one function and trying it with another etc. It's best used for "example" type tests (i.e. how do I use this function?)

Unit tests can be larger and more involved than doctests.

Comment: That's not true, you can also write all your doctests in a separate file, and do whatever you want.

Comment: You can also [have doctests of individual functions _share_ their execution context (variables, results, ...)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242443/1090455).

Answer (score 0):

Some tests will need things like databases set up and initialised.

This could make doctests:

- **very verbose** (and therefore not good
  documentation); and
- **probably inefficient** because in doctests you would typically set 
  up the database for each function or class. In comparison, 
  unit tests more easily could use the
  same database to test many functions
  or classes.

Comment: That's not true, you can control the context of execution for you doctests ... create some variables that are shared between all your tests in a same module for example. So no need to redo the same for all functions.

Comment: Indeed, there's even an easy method for using a shared execution context for all callables in one module: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242443/1090455