# object reuse in python doctest

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

I have a sample doctest like this one.

```
"""
This is the "iniFileGenerator" module.
>>> hintFile = "./tests/unit_test_files/hint.txt"
>>> f = iniFileGenerator(hintFile)
>>> print f.hintFilePath
./tests/unit_test_files/hint.txt
"""
class iniFileGenerator:
    def __init__(self, hintFilePath):
        self.hintFilePath = hintFilePath
    def hello(self):
        """
        >>> f.hello()
        hello
        """
        print "hello"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

When I execute this code, I got this error.

```
Failed example:
    f.hello()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/doctest.py", line 1254, in __run
        compileflags, 1) in test.globs
      File "<doctest __main__.iniFileGenerator.hello[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        f.hello()
    NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

This error is caused by accessing 'f' which was not accessible when testing `hello()` method.

Is there any way to share the object which is created before? Without it, one need to create object all the time when it's necessary.

```
def hello(self):
    """
    hintFile = "./tests/unit_test_files/hint.txt"
    >>> f = iniFileGenerator(hintFile)
    >>> f.hello()
    hello
    """
    print "hello"
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#what-s-the-execution-context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `testmod(extraglobs={'f': initFileGenerator('')})` to define a reusable object globally.

As the [doctest doc](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#doctest.testmod) says,

> *extraglobs* gives a dict merged into the globals used to execute examples. This works like dict.update()

But I used to test all methods in `__doc__` of class before all methods.

```
class MyClass(object):
    """MyClass
    >>> m = MyClass()
    >>> m.hello()
    hello
    >>> m.world()
    world
    """

    def hello(self):
        """method hello"""
        print 'hello'

    def world(self):
        """method world"""
        print 'world'
```

Comment: just beat me to it, yep on extraglobs. Although I don't like the extraglobs approach, I like this answer less - some of the point of doctests are to document the methods, which you lose here.

Comment: @Thomas After I checked the source code of some popular and well-documented projects, I think it is ok, http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/align.html#Alignment

Comment: Cool - I just like to see it in the docstrings so I can call help() on the method to see how it works instead of scrolling through the class docs.

Comment: There may be [a more convenient approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242443/1090455).

Answer (score 2):

To obtain literate modules with tests that all use a shared execution context (i.e. individual tests that can share and re-use results), one has to look at the relevant part of [documentation on the execution context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#what-s-the-execution-context), which says:

> ... each time `doctest` finds a docstring to test, it uses a *shallow* **copy** of `M`‘s globals, so that running tests doesn’t change the module’s real globals, and so that one test in `M` can’t leave behind crumbs that accidentally allow another test to work.
>
> ...
>
> You can **force use of *your own* dict** as the execution context by passing `globs=your_dict` to `testmod()` or `testfile()` instead.

Given this, [I managed to reverse-engineer](https://gist.github.com/kernc/0dccae6542465d59a331) from `doctest` module that besides using copies (i.e. the `dict`'s `copy()` method), it also clears the globals dict (using `clear()`) after each test.

Thus, one can patch their own globals dictionary with something like:

```
class Context(dict):
    def clear(self):
        pass
    def copy(self):
        return self
```

and then use it as:

```
import doctest
from importlib import import_module

module = import_module('some.module')
doctest.testmod(module,
                # Make a copy of globals so tests in this
                # module don't affect the tests in another
                glob=Context(module.__dict__.copy()))
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me that finds this, here's an easy hack that solves this problem.

In your module documentation, attach the "global" values as a property of the `builtins` module, e.g.

```py
"""
My module documentation

>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.sample_value = "Here is a long value"
>>> builtins.sample_func = lambda x: x.lower()
"""
```

The `builtins` module is automatically imported into every scope, and so its properties will be available in your functions, including doctest functions

```py
def first_char_func(s: str) -> str:
   """
   Returns the first char of a function

   >>> first_char_func(sample_func(sample_value))
   h
   """  
   return s[0] if len(s) > 0 else None
```

Arguably however, once you've gotten to this stage, you're better off just writing a unit test.